Gabb Phone Z2 not prompting me for USB file transfer
I always use my Gabb Phone Z2 for transferring videos to watch on road trips, but it's different now. I was about to transfer some episodes to my phone, and it always prompted me to choose either file transfer or charging only. But 3 days ago, I didn't get that prompt. It only started charging, and file transfer did not work.
I restarted my phone, the computer, and factory reset my phone but still nothing.
Is this a system or phone issue, or is it related to my charger or something else?

On recent phones there is not directly shown prompt, instead a notification message should appear where you can chose the USB mode. If it does not appear the cable can be defect (charging and data use different wires inside the cable, so the data wires may be damaged while charging stil works fine).

The two most likely scenarios are

You are using a different cable.  Cables come in many configurations such as


Data only

Power only

Data and Power
The current cable probably only has wires to do charging.  It is not a data cable.



The cable used to work before, but it doesn't now.  In which case, the cable is damaged.  Try a different cable that is meant for data.

